# Set HTML5 contenteditable div to pristine

Tags: angularjs, html, contenteditable

JSP snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label style="font-size: larger;">Description:</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="form-control" name="createWorkSpc" ng-model="newWorkspace.description" required contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 100px; color: grey; overflow: auto; height: 100px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 4px;"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span ng-show="workspaceTitleAndDesc.workspace_name.$dirty && workspaceTitleAndDesc.createWorkSpc.$error.required" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS directive snippet:

```
directive('contenteditable',function($sce){
         return {
              restrict: 'A',
              require: '?ngModel',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                  if (!ngModel) return;

                  ngModel.$render = function() {
                    element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
                  };

                  element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
                    scope.$evalAsync(read);
                  });

                  read();

                 /* ngModel.$validators.contenteditable = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                    if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                      return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                  };*/

                  /*ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                        if (value === '') {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('syntaxError', false);
                        } else {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('syntaxError', true);
                        }

                        return value;
                    });*/

                  function read() {
                    var html = element.html();
                    if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
                      html = '';
                    }
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
                  }
              }
            };
    })
```

**Used** ng-form="workspaceTitleAndDesc" , model="newWorkspace"

The span has to be shown when the contenteditable div has some error. But on form load also I get the span, because the div is dirty instead being pristine.

I had written formatters and validators for the div , but nothing seems to work. I have posted this code as commented code.

**How to make contenteditable div pristine on form load?**